# Can a post be protected from its author?

Tags: discussion

Can a post in a thread that is protected be locked so that author cannot edit it? Sometimes authors keep piling so much stuff on the question that it would serve the community better if post is rolled back and locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. However, this is a last resort since it goes against what the SE model stands for.

Steps to take before locking:

1. Comment and tell the user this is not a good practice. Link to the [Help] if necessary.
2. Vote to close: Needs focus.
3. Flag for mod attention if the issue persists. Usually a mod message to explain the situation suffices.

Comment: Yeah i understand that. But i was just wodering if its possible to do.